# Should I use IndexedDB for web-app?

Tags: html, indexeddb

I'm planning to build a web-app to do automated quizzing for some language classes I teach. The initial mock-ups have been built as a Drupal module, so it stores everything in a mySQL database accessed through php. I'm wondering, though, whether another data-storage technology would make the app more portable in the long run. I'd like to be able to port versions that could be run offline and natively on mobile platforms. I've been toying with trying out the new IndexedDB technology that Firefox and Google seem to be buying into, but it's still so raw that I'm worried it will change too much. The regular offline storage option in HTML5 seems to lack any kind of relational capabilities, just storing a flat list of key-value pairs. Are there other options I'm missing for web/offline portability? Would people recommend IndexedDB at this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main usage of IndexedDB API is to store data locally on browser side, so that offline mode is supported, for eg. you should be able to read your already downloaded mails. This will make things faster and reduce network latency.

If I understand correctly what you want is a portable storage for quizzing. You do not want students to know the correct answer is till they answer a question. Now if you want them to answer and then evaluate the answer, then indexedDB is not a solution. It will make students write code/scripts to get the data from DB and cheat.

Comment: Right, I hadn't thought of that. So I'd probably need either to stay server-side or to produce a separate desktop app in a compiled language. Thanks.

Comment: HTML is most portable. Client-server is easy as long as you as network access.

Comment: This is like 4 years old, but I wonder, could you salt/hash the answers to the questions so that they can only be matched like a password?  Wonder if that would work.